# Javascript split JSON object by key

Tags: javascript, json

I have a situation where i need to split the Json Object given by back-end using the key. Here is the example of the JSON the back-end gave.

```
{
    "answer": {
        "E2": "Tony Stark",
        "E3": "1",
        "E4": "2",
        "E6": "4",
        "E8": "9120",
        "E9": "01",
        "F1": "Marvel",
        "F2": "1",
        "F4": "2",
        "F6": "4",
        "F8": "9120",
        "F9": "01",
        "G1": "02",
        "G2": "02",
        "G3": "02",
        "H10": "Car"
    }
}
```

Is it possible for me to split the answer into per section E, F, G and H ? Expected result to be

```
{
    "answer": [
        {
            "E2": "Tony Stark",
            "E3": "1",
            "E4": "2",
            "E6": "4",
            "E8": "9120",
            "E9": "01",
            "sectionName": "E"
        },
        {
            "F1": "Marvel",
            "F2": "1",
            "F4": "2",
            "F6": "4",
            "F8": "9120",
            "F9": "01",
            "sectionName": "F"
        },
        {
            "G1": "02",
            "G2": "02",
            "G3": "02",
            "sectionName": "G"
        },
        {
            "H10": "Car",
            "sectionName": "H"
        }
    ]
}
```

There must be a genius out there that might be able to solve my question. Thank you so much. 
Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: You can use reduce function probably

Comment: any explanation on how to achieve this ? I really newbie in this javascript thing.

Comment: You could just loop over the keys and add them to a new object that is sorted like your example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loop through the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object and group them based on the first letter of the key. If the group object alrady has the the letter as key, update it. Else, add the letter as key to the group object. Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the array of `answer` needed in the output

```js
const input={answer:{E2:"Tony Stark",E3:"1",E4:"2",E6:"4",E8:"9120",E9:"01",F1:"Marvel",F2:"1",F4:"2",F6:"4",F8:"9120",F9:"01",G1:"02",G2:"02",G3:"02",H10:"Car"}};

const group = {};

for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(input.answer)) {
  const sectionName = k.charAt(0);
  if (group[sectionName])
    group[sectionName][k] = v;
  else
    group[sectionName] = { sectionName, [k]: v };
}

const answer = Object.values(group)

console.log({ answer })
```

Answer (score 3):

loop through the entries on the `answer` object like this -

```js
let a =
{
    "answer":
    {
        "E2": "Tony Stark",
        "E3": "1",
        "E4": "2",
        "E6": "4",
        "E8": "9120",
        "E9": "01",
        "F1": "Marvel",
        "F2": "1",
        "F4": "2",
        "F6": "4",
        "F8": "9120",
        "F9": "01",
        "G1": "02",
        "G2": "02",
        "G3": "02",
        "H10": "Car"
    }
};

//map of sections by section name
let m = new Map();
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(a.answer))
{
  let sectionName = key.charAt(0);
  let section = m.get(sectionName);
  if (!section)
  {
    section =
    {
      sectionName
    };
    m.set(sectionName, section);
  }
  section[key] = value;
}
//create final object
let b =
{
  answer: [...m.entries()].sort(([k1], [k2]) => k1.localeCompare(k2))
               .map(([key, value]) => value)
};
console.log(b);
```

```
//map of sections by section name
let m = new Map();
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(a.answer))
{
  let sectionName = key.charAt(0);
  let section = m.get(sectionName);
  if (!section) {
    section = {
      sectionName
    };
    m.set(sectionName, section);
  }
  section[key] = value;
}
//create final object
let b = {
  answer: [...m.entries()].sort(([k1], [k2]) => k1.localeCompare(k2))
               .map(([key, value]) => value)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group with the `sectionName` and an object as hash table and get only the value of it as result.

```js
var data = { answer: { E2: "Tony Stark", E3: "1", E4: "2", E6: "4", E8: "9120", E9: "01", F1: "Marvel", F2: "1", F4: "2", F6: "4", F8: "9120", F9: "01", G1: "02", G2: "02", G3: "02", H10: "Car" } },
    result = Object.values(Object.entries(data.answer).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        var sectionName = k[0];
        r[sectionName] = r[sectionName] || { sectionName };
        r[sectionName][k] = v;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```js
const input = {"answer": { "E2": "Tony Stark", "E3": "1", "E4": "2", "E6": "4", "E8": "9120", "E9": "01", "F1": "Marvel", "F2": "1", "F4": "2", "F6": "4", "F8": "9120", "F9": "01", "G1": "02", "G2": "02", "G3": "02", "H10": "Car" }}

const key_map = {}
const final = {
  answer: []
}
Object.keys(input.answer).map(key => {
  if (!key_map[key[0]]) {
    key_map[key[0]] = {
      "sectionName": key[0]
    }
  }
  key_map[key[0]][key] =input.answer[key]
})

Object.values(key_map).map((v) => {
  final.answer.push(v)
})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work

```
let myObject = {
  'answer': {
    'E2': 'Tony Stark',
    'E3': '1',
    'E4': '2',
    'E6': '4',
    'E8': '9120',
    'E9': '01',
    'F1': 'Marvel',
    'F2': '1',
    'F4': '2',
    'F6': '4',
    'F8': '9120',
    'F9': '01',
    'G1': '02',
    'G2': '02',
    'G3': '02',
    'H10': 'Car'
  }
}
let myResult = []
for (let index in myObject.answer) {
  let sectionName = index.substr(0, 1)
  let indexFound = myResult.findIndex(r => r.sectionName === sectionName)
  if (indexFound >= 0) {
    myResult[indexFound][index] = myObject.answer[index]
  } else {
    myResult.push({ 'sectionName': sectionName })
    myResult[(myResult.length - 1)][index] = myObject.answer[index]
  }
}
console.log({
  answer: myResult
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const jsonInout = `{
  "answer": {
      "E2": "Tony Stark",
      "E3": "1",
      "E4": "2",
      "E6": "4",
      "E8": "9120",
      "E9": "01",
      "F1": "Marvel",
      "F2": "1",
      "F4": "2",
      "F6": "4",
      "F8": "9120",
      "F9": "01",
      "G1": "02",
      "G2": "02",
      "G3": "02",
      "H10": "Car"
  }
}`;

// Parse response
let obj = JSON.parse(jsonInout, null, 2).answer;

// Get sections
const sections = Array.from(new Set(Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
  return key[0];
})));

// Get splitted object
const splitted = {
  answer: sections.map(sectionKey => {
    let section = { sectionName: sectionKey };
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if (key[0] === sectionKey) section[key] = value;
    }
    return section;
  })
};

console.log(splitted);
```